# Flip a probability tree in R

Tags: r, probability, decision-tree, probability-theory

Currently taking a course on decision analysis. There is a concept called "flipping a probability tree", illustrated in the following example.

[image]

May I know:

(1) Is there a way to do the above **graphically** in R? I tried looking at packages like `rpart`, `party`, `rpart.plot` but didn't get very far.

(2) If graphical representation is not possible, are there existing R functions that can easily calculate the various branch probabilities, endpoint probabilities?

Comment: Note that rpart, party and rpart.plot are packages to fit classification/regression trees, which are a different concept to probability trees.

Comment: @Hong Ooi, thank you. So are you aware of R functions / packages that can do the above?

Comment: I don't know if there are `R` package(s) that will draw probability trees with a few lines of code. But if you're willing to put in some effort, here are three resources for learning how draw node-and-edge diagrams with lower-level commands: [How To Plot A Graph Using Rgraphviz](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Rgraphviz/inst/doc/Rgraphviz.pdf); [Improving the 'gridGraphviz' package in R](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/gridGraphviz/gridGraphviz.html); [Drawing Diagrams with R](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009-1/RJournal_2009-1_Murrell.pdf).

Comment: @dwstu: Can you share the course? I am trying to learn this stuff.